# PL/pgSQL Loops Indefinitely

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I want to loop between two dates but my PL/pgSQL code goes into indefinite loop. I think I'm missing something here.

```
do $$
    declare
        the_dates date;
    begin
        select gs from generate_series('2019-11-01'::date, '2012-11-30', '1 day') as gs into the_dates;
        loop
            raise notice '%', the_dates;
        end loop;
    end
$$
```

How should I loop between these 2 dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping over the result of the SELECT statement.

If you want to loop over the result of a query you [need to use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) `for record in select ...`

```
do $$
declare
  l_date_row record;
begin
  for l_date_row in select gs 
                    from generate_series('2012-11-30'::date, '2019-11-01'::date, '1 day') as gs
    raise notice '%', l_date_row.gs;
  end loop;
end
$$
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be confused as to the syntax for loops.

What you have here are two separate things:

1. A query that select zero rows (because you have your dates backwards) into a date variable.
2. A loop with no limits that will raise a notice forever.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING